# Spock framework has conflict with other plugins in Grails 1.3.8

Tags: grails, spock

I have installed Spock on Grails 1.3.8 application. It fails after running the test-app. It seems it has some conflicts with my other plugins but I cannot figure it out. I have over 20 plugins installed.

The error is :

```
     org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
     Could not instantiate global transform class  
     org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:
     /C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/xxxxxxx/.ivy2/cache/org.spock
     framework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.6-groovy-1.8.jar!/META-INF/services  
     /org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception 
     org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock 
     compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 0.6.0-groovy-1.8 is not compatible  
     with Groovy 1.7.8. For  more information,see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org
     Spock location: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/xxxxxx/.ivy2/cache
     /org.spockframework
     /spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.6-groovy-1.8.jar
     Groovy location: file:/C:/dev/Grails/grails-1.3.8/lib/groovy-all-1.7.8.jar
```

Here is my buildConfig:

```
dependencies {
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.6-groovy-1.7"
}
plugins {
    compile ":joda-time:1.4"
    compile ":excel-import:0.9.6"
    compile ":export:1.3"

    test(":spock:0.6") {
      exclude "spock-grails-support"
  }
}
```

I am able to run the spock test without any issue if I dont install any plugin. I am not sure if there is something specific to one of the plugins or something about Spock or even anything I am doing wrong.

Additional Information: 
I found out that for some reason one/more of the plugins prevents Grails from downloading the

spock-grails-support:0.6-groovy-1.7

With my plugins, Grails only download the spock-grails-support:0.6-groovy-1.8 not 1.7 that is required for 1.3.8. 
So now I am not sure what is preventing Grails from downloading the dependency.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that Joda-time plugin has a dependency on Spock, although, it has set the export to false in the plugin, it was forcing the Grails to download the spock-grails-support:0.6-groovy-1.8 in my application. I had it to exclude the spock and so far it seems its working.

```
compile (":joda-time:1.4") { exclude "spock" }
```